# How to add an element to an empty JSON in python?

Tags: python, json

I created an empty string & convert it into a JSON by `json.dump`. Once I want to add element, it fails & show

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

I tried both `json.insert` & `json.append` but neither of them works.

It seems that it's data type problem. As Python can't declare data type as Java & C can, how can I avoid the problem?

```
import json

data = {}
json_data = json.dumps(data)
json_data.append(["A"]["1"])
print (json_data)
```

Comment: Add it to the dictionary (not a string) *before* you dump it to a string (not *"a JSON"*)?

Answer (score 4):

JSON is a string representation of data, such as lists and dictionaries. You don't append to the JSON, you append to the original data and then dump it.

Also, you don't use `append()` with dictionaries, it's used with lists.

```
data = {} # This is a dictionary
data["a"] = "1"; # Add an item to the dictionary
json_data = json.dumps(data) # Convert the dictionary to a JSON string
print(json_data)
```

Comment: it looks like OP is confused about what is what, i,e, `data` is not string, but `dict` and json_data is in fact string, etc. Maybe add some explanation about that if you like

Comment: I've added some explanation of the difference.

Comment: Thanks! It's works.
So if I want to add new element, I need to convert the json string back to dict instead of deal with json string directly?