# BeautifulSoup can't find element class in HTML

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape this page have 10 `class='name main-name'`, like this:[sample source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62NLX.png)

but when i code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = requests.get("https://genvita.vn/thu-thach/7-ngay-detox-da-dep-dang-thon-nguoi-khoe-qua-soc-len-den-8-trieu-dong")

c = result.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")

comment_items = soup.find_all('div', class_="name main-name")
print(len(comment_items)
```

but return : 0 not return : 10. I have tried search and use many solutions in stackoverflow but cann't fix

Comment: Do you mean to find all `soup.find_all('div',class='main-name')` instead of `soup.find_all('div', class_="user-name")`? Alternatively `soup.find_all('span', class="user-name")`

Comment: The `user-name` class is on the span. You should do `soup.find_all('span',class_='user-name')` instead

Comment: sr @Mazz, i tried 'soup.find_all('span',class_='user-name')' and 'soup.find_all('div', class_="name main-name")' but it not working.

Comment: that generated dynamically and is not part of the source code when you request it. You need to use something like Selenium that will render the page first. Or, search within the html code within the scripts. What exactly are you trying to scrape?

Comment: @chitown i want to craper comment it that site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because div `name main-name` doens't appear in your `DOM` . In this case using `Selenium` is more powerful than `BeautifulSoap`

```
from  selenium import webdriver

driver_path = r'Your Chrome driver path'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
browser.get("https://genvita.vn/thu-thach/7-ngay-detox-da-dep-dang-thon-nguoi-khoe-qua-soc-len-den-8-trieu-dong")

get_element  = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='name main-name']")
print len(get_element)

browser.close()
```

OUTPUT :

```
10
```

And you can also get names like:

```
 for users in get_element:
    print(users.text)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Phạm Thị Kim Chi
My Linh Nguyen
Mr Vinh Bảo Hiểm Sức Khoẻ Sắc Đẹp
Ngô Thị Tuyết
Huỳnh Thị Bích Trâm
Linh Trúc Diêm
Nguyen Tu
Nguyen Thom
Hồ Thu Trang
Trầnthịtrắng
```

Comment: Im a newbie so i dont know how to use selenium, your example will help me to get some date in div nam main-name. Thanks you so much

Comment: But can i ask you a question? I found BeautifulSoup help get data comment from 'import Comment', can i use this solve my error?

Comment: Comment using for get html in comment line . Your datas isn't in Comment line so It doesn't help you.This is the document of Selenium I hope it helps https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/ @ToanNguyenPhuoc

Comment: Thanks, and this is a last question. I want to write data in json file like this : 
`comment{

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53882454/how-to-add-an-element-to-an-empty-json-in-python will help you @ToanNguyenPhuoc

Comment: sr, in yesterday my internet very lag so i can't edit and explan my question. In my website i get data, have 31 comments, but i use solution you give me, just take 10 comments. Do you help me take all data from 31 comments?

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in the comments, it's generated dynamically. So here's an implementation with Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://genvita.vn/thu-thach/7-ngay-detox-da-dep-dang-thon-nguoi-khoe-qua-soc-len-den-8-trieu-dong"

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

c = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")

comment_items = soup.find_all('div', {'class':"name main-name"})
print (len(comment_items))

driver.close()
```

**Output:**

```
print (len(comment_items))
10
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use beautifulsoup4 select function

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = requests.get("https://genvita.vn/thu-thach/7-ngay-detox-da-dep-dang-thon-nguoi-khoe-qua-soc-len-den-8-trieu-dong")

c = result.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")

comment_items = soup.select("div.name.main-name")
print(len(comment_items))
```